# How can I run the compiled version of hiphop php hhvm of wordpress installation?

Tags: php, hhvm

I would like to run the compiled version of hiphop php hhvm of wordpress. That is, without the php source code on production server. Can anyone tell me how to get it done? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
hhvm --hphp -thhbc -o some_dir file1.php file2.php
```

https://github.com/facebook/hiphop-php/wiki/Running-PHP-programs-with-HHVM#using-repoauthoritative-mode